# Android Broadcast Receiver SharedPreferences empty on initial Activity's onResume

Tags: android, referrer

Here's my `onResume` call in the `MainActivity`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(INSTALL_PREFERENCE, 0);
    String referrerString = settings.getString(REFERRAL_KEY, null);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<~>();
    if (referrerString != null){
         params.put("referrer", referrerString);
    }
}
```

Here's my `onResume` in the class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        try{
            String referrerString = intent.getStringExtra("referrer");

            if(null != referrerString){
                String referrer = URLEncoder.encode(referrerString, "UTF-8");
                context.getSharedPreferences(INSTALL_PREFERENCE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString(REFERRAL_KEY, referrer).commit();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //don't handle exceptions for now
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I call the `MainActivity` by opening the app, my app will not return the `referrer` on the first open. Is there a reason the `SharedPreferences` will not store my `referrer` on the first application open? I want to pass back the `referrer` on the first open and not the second.

Answer (score 1):

on resume() will be executed before the broadcast receiver and hence for the first time you might be receiving null or default value for the referrer and at later pont of time if you reopen the activity you might be getting correct value because onReceive() would have executed by this time.

If your application has any settings preference screen which actually initialises the settings only after opening it  so you may have to initialises all the preferences with default values before using it. It could be the reason that sometimes if you open the application you are getting correct values because you might have opened the setting screen.

Comment: Is there a way to make sure I can get this on the first app open?

Comment: Do you know where this behavior is documented?

Comment: It is not documented rather it is my personal experience

Comment: How did you test this?

Comment: On application startup you should be able to read correct preference values every time. Rest you would be having idea what is expected result

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could fix it.  Make your Activity implement the [OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener.html) interface, which will call the `onSharedPreferenceChanged()` callback when any value in the SharedPreference file registered changes.

If the timing is right and you get a value in `onResume()`, just carry on as you do in your current code.

If you don't have a value yet, then show a ProgressDialog, and wait for the BroadcastReceiver to populate the value.
Once the value is modified by the BroadcastReceiver, capture the value in `onSharedPreferenceChanged()`, and then use it as needed.

Here is the general structure of the solution:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    SharedPreferences settings;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Map<String, String> params;
    String INSTALL_PREFERENCE = "installpref";
    String REFERRAL_KEY = "referral";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        params = new HashMap<String, String>();

        settings = this.getSharedPreferences(INSTALL_PREFERENCE, 0);

        settings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this); //added
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        String referrerString = settings.getString(REFERRAL_KEY, null);
        if (referrerString != null){
            params.put("referrer", referrerString);
            //call whatever methods need params to have a value
            //.......
        }
        else{
            //Show progress dialog and wait for BroadcastReceiver to populate referrer
            dialog.setMessage("loading");
            dialog.show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPrefs, String key) {

        if (key.equals(REFERRAL_KEY)){

            //dismiss dialog if it's showing
            if (dialog.isShowing()){
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            String referrerString = sharedPrefs.getString(REFERRAL_KEY, null);
            if (referrerString != null){
                params.put("referrer", referrerString);
                //call whatever methods need params to have a value
                //.......
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this actually changes anything since the app will launch and the main activity will run all the callbacks without shared prefs being stored.

Comment: @locoboy you can't delay the lifecycle of the Activity (nor would you want to), so the best thing to do is give the user feedback that you're waiting for something, and then get the value as fast as possible, then update the UI once you get the value.

Comment: The issue isn't that I want to give the user feedback, the issue is that the `referrer` is something that I need in the `MainActivity` on the first app launch. I also don't want to wait for it and make the rest of the app hang.

Comment: @locoboy That is the whole point of this solution, it enables MainActivity to get the value as fast as possible without making the app hang.

Answer (score 0):

The referrer broadcast is sent slightly after the main component of your app is started. Therefore, you must notify your activity once the broadcast is received.
One simple solution would be to use LocalBroadcastManager between the Receiver and the Activity:

```
/* BroadcastReceiver */

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String referrer = (String) extras.get(KEY_REFERRER);
    // save String to SharedPrefrences
    Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_UPDATE);
    intent.putExtra(KEY_REFERRER, referrer);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

/*****/

/* Activity*/

private final BroadcastReceiver mUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_REFERRER);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mUpdateReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mUpdateReceiver, new IntentFilter(ReferrerReceiver.ACTION_UPDATE));
    super.onResume();
}
```

If you need a fully fonctional sample code/app, check out my OpenSource project on [GitHub](https://github.com/SimonMarquis/Android-InstallReferrer).